# How to run hive server 2 as a background, don't get terminated on closing terminal

Tags: hive, ubuntu-14.04

My hive server 2 command runs properly on (aws)ubuntu terminal:

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10002 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=LOG,console
```

but when i closed the terminal my hive server stop,
i want a command to solve this problem thanks.

Comment: What about `nohup ...... &`

Answer (score 1):

At last after searching so much i found this command :-

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10002 2 &  > /dev/null
```

After running this process you will get an process id save it some where, it will be needed when you need to kill the same process , i am doing like this :)